# Google Anayltics "_trackEvent" not getting logged

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement event tracking for Google Analytics, and it seems like everything is firing correctly using the [Chrome Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en):

[image]

However the only thing getting logged in the GA account is the initial _trackPageview call on the `index.html` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-40625622-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'dietcoke.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/22']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

This is a one-page javascript app, where all routing is happening client-side using hashes.  Here is an example call that will trigger what's in the screenshot above:

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','entry','share_facebook', username]);`

where `username` is a string.

Comment: Try changing one line from
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/22']);
to
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

I am no expert in it but in one of my application above line is written like that

Comment: @KamranShahid the issue isn't with the trackPageView, it's with firing the events.  The _trackPageView call is successfully registering.

Answer (score 2):

The event is getting sent. There's no question about that.

If you're not seeing the hit, one of three things is happening, and all involve some form of user error.

Either:

- You're looking at the wrong date ranges.
- You're not looking in the event section.
- You have a profile level filter that is somehow excluding your events. (I think this is the most likely.)

Incidentally, I went to the page in question (I thought the setDomainName was a joke, but apparently not), and manually triggered the event in question. I can confirm it's firing as intended, and sent to the same account as your pageview.

Comment: Just had this problem myself. Can't confirm 100% yet, but I'm 99% sure it's because we have a profile level filter that excludes IP's from our company locations (where I am testing from), as you suspected.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with:

```
console.log(username);
```

Before you do the _trackEvent to check the program is reaching that part of your code. Can be a dumb problem. 
In any case, the trackEvent should be done anyway if "username" is undefined.

Like @yahel says, you could do another test: 
Open you GA account and check the RealTime Analytics. You should see the trackEvent ping immediately. Most likely its working and you don't see the data before.